# Finding the circulation and the outward flux across the boundary of a given region

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

Given: (, ) = 〈ln(2 + 2), arctan(y/x)〉

where R is the annulus {(, }: 1 ≤ ⁡ ≤ 2⁡, 0⁡ ≤ ⁡ ≤ 2.

compute for the circulation and outward flux across the boundary of the given region.

The first thing I know is to use the normal form for the outward flux and tangential flux for the circulation. But what do you do with the region R? thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "what do you do with the region $R$"? You find its boundaries, and compute the circulation and outward flux across those boundaries. What else would you do with it?

Comment: Do I need to convert it to rectangular coordinates?